# Configuring Cisco 3800 ISR Router with two default gateways for different subnets

Tags: cisco, router

I am trying to configure two physical interfaces on a Cisco router to act as two separate gateways for two different subnets:

gigabitEthernet0/0 > gw 10.10.10.10 255.255.0.0 for network 10.10.0.0
gigabitEthernet0/1 > gw 10.15.10.10 255.255.0.0 for network 10.15.0.0

Should I be using rip version 2 routing or can I just use static routing to do this?. If you can provide an example for doing this, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: What model router?

Comment: Cisco 3800 Series

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable and configure Policy Based Routing (PBR). Try the guide first and let us know if you have any problems: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfpbr.html

Note the "Differing Next Hops Example" at the very bottom:

```
access-list 1 permit 209.165.200.225
access-list 2 permit 209.165.200.226
!
interface ethernet 1
 ip policy route-map Texas
!
route-map Texas permit 10
 match ip address 1
 set ip precedence priority
 set ip next-hop 209.165.200.227
!
route-map Texas permit 20
 match ip address 2
 set ip precedence critical
 set ip next-hop 209.165.200.228
```

Comment: For some reason, I was able to ping hosts on 10.15.x.x network from 10.10.x.x network after I applied PBR on the router. But now I can't. I am wondering what happened overnight. I appreciate your help again. I also didn't apply the next-hop line since it's a closed network with one router.